# Federal Shutdown: Raw SNAP (Food Stamps) participation data source

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, federal

With the Federal government shut down, my source of raw SNAP participation rates is gone (both USDA and Data.gov are offline). Any suggestions about where I could find this data?

Any suggestions of mirrors, alternative sources, or reports with average rates per year would all be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this helpful?

**Monthly Data -- National Level:
FY 2011 through June 2013**

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:r9JbtaubWlMJ:www.fns.usda.gov/pd/34snapmonthly.htm

**Annual State Level Data:
FY 2008-2012**

- [Persons Participating](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWn9FRq5RWxgJ%3awww.fns.usda.gov/pd/15SNAPpartPP.htm)
- [Households Participating](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWn9FRq5RWxgJ%3awww.fns.usda.gov/pd/16SNAPpartHH.htm)
- [Benefits](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWn9FRq5RWxgJ%3awww.fns.usda.gov/pd/17SNAPfyBEN%24.htm)
- [Average Monthly Benefit Per Person](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWn9FRq5RWxgJ%3awww.fns.usda.gov/pd/18SNAPavg%24PP.htm)
- [Average Monthly Benefit Per Household](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWn9FRq5RWxgJ%3awww.fns.usda.gov/pd/19SNAPavg%24HH.htm)

Comment: Thanks! Using your answer, I ended up here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TLd17PTcZMEJ:www.fns.usda.gov/pd/SNAPsummary.htm+&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us, which was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Google Cache, there's also archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/20130922064932/http://www.fns.usda.gov/